# Ruby : Fiber yield and fiber.resume with arguments -

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby.. and I am new to programming

```
fiber = Fiber.new do |first|
  second = Fiber.yield first + 2
end

puts fiber.resume 10
puts fiber.resume 14
puts fiber.resume 18

12
14
FiberError: dead fiber called
```

what I think is, first fiber.resume call executes all statements before first Fiber.yield, when Fiber.yield is executed it transfers control to the line after first fiber.resume and the value (first+2) becomes return value of first fiber.resume so puts fiber.resume prints 12, so here next line is also fiber.resume. Now, First Fiber.yield transferred control, so the next line after Fiber.yield should be executed when you call the second fiber.resume. But there is no statement after first Fiber.yield then how do I get 14. I read we can get the last statement, but it's not getting the input from the fiber.resume, and it is not even there.

and without block local variable

```
irb(main):007:0> fiber = Fiber.new do |first|
irb(main):008:1* Fiber.yield first + 2
irb(main):009:1> end
=> #<Fiber:0x23fb4a0>
irb(main):010:0>
irb(main):011:0* puts fiber.resume 10
12
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> puts fiber.resume 10
10
=> nil
irb(main):013:0> puts fiber.resume 10
FiberError: dead fiber called
        from (irb):13:in `resume'
        from (irb):13
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
irb(main):014:0>
```

Please help me understand how it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> first `fiber.resume` call executes all statements before first `Fiber.yield`, when `Fiber.yield` is executed it transfers control to the line after first `fiber.resume` and the value (`first+2`) becomes return value of first `fiber.resume` so `puts fiber.resume` prints `12`

That is almost correct. The block actually stops already here:

```
fiber = Fiber.new do |first|
  second = ...
```

The fiber is suspended in the middle of that assignment. The assignment cannot be completed, because `Fiber.yield` yields control back to the calling context, passing `12`.

The call `fiber.resume 14` then resumes the fiber, and the assignment can be completed:

```
fiber = Fiber.new do |first|
  second = 14
```

`14` is the value passed by the second resume.

The block can finish now and `fiber.resume` returns. But this time, the return value is determined by the block's return value (which is `14`, because `second = 14` evaluates to `14`).

Maybe it becomes more obvious this way:

```
fiber = Fiber.new do |first|
  second = Fiber.yield first + 2
  third = Fiber.yield second + 3
  third + 4
end

puts fiber.resume 10
# prints 12 (10 + 2)
puts fiber.resume 14
# prints 17 (14 + 3)
puts fiber.resume 16
# prints 20 (16 + 4)
puts fiber.resume 18
# dead fiber called (FiberError)
```

Comment: Thanks bro I took so much time to understand